# Passing touch events to ScrollView's Parent

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a layout similar to this:

```
<FrameLayout>
   <ScrollView>
      <RelativeLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I want ScrollView to work normally with Vertical gesture(scroll/fling) and Pass horizontal gestures to it's parent(FrameLayout has Drag functionality and works fine without a ScrollView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new class extending FrameLayout and ovverriding `onInterceptTouchEvents` than you can perform your logic and decide which events must be sent to the scrollview and which ones must be handle inside the FrameLayout `onTouchEvent`

You can check the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overide onInterceptTouchEvent() to pass the touch event to its parent view. For your reference please go through this link https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html